# Compare content of two Cell and show new words included in cell in Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two Row.Give it a name Row A1 and Row A2. The content of each cell are as below.

Row A1  = Ram,shyam,Steve,Jack ( Max 100 Character)
Row A2 = Ram,Tom,Steve,Michael,Linda (Max 100 Character)

Each character is separated by ",". Now what i want is to compare Row A1 and Row A2 and point out the difference in Row A3 and Row A4. my desired value for Row A3 and A4. Are as below.

Row A3 = Shyam,Jack ( It should show only words which are not available in Row A2.

Row A4 = Tom,Michael,Linda ( It should show only words which are new in Row A2.

Comment: Share your code with us.

Answer (score 0):

In your apps script, convert each cell (A1 and A2) to separate lists using the .toList(","). you can then set up a for loop where:

```
a3List = [];
for (var i=0;i<a1List.length;i++){
  if(!a2List.contains(a1List[i]){
      a3List.push(a1List[i]);
  }
}
```

you can then repeat this method for the other comparison.

Please post your code for troubleshooting if you have any problems!